# Need Query to Delete Duplicates Between Two Files in SQL

Tags: sql

SQL newbie.

Imported two files into the claims table (Claims). File 4028 has 6,721 rows and File 2090 has 4,707 rows. Both files have the same columns (Amt, First, Last, FillDate).

Used the following query to identify duplicates:

```
SELECT first, last, amt, filldate, COUNT(*) AS duplicatecount
FROM Claims
WHERE fileid IN (4028, 2090)
GROUP BY first, last, amt, filldate
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY 1,2 DESC
```

Need query to delete the duplicates between the two files. Delete from file 2090.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to use `EXISTS` to ensure a duplicate exists when deleting.

```
DELETE C
FROM Claims C
WHERE C.fileId = 2090
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM Claims D
    WHERE 
        D.fileid = 4028 
    AND C.first = D.first 
    AND C.last = D.last
    AND C.amt = D.amt
    AND C.filldate = D.filldate
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE * FROM Claims WHERE fileid = 2090 AND first IN (the query you used to find the duplicates)
```

Try this... And please let me know if it works....

Answer (score 0):

You may use a correlated subquery.

```
   delete * from yourtable a
   inner join 
   (select  fileid, first, last, amt, filldate             
    from yourtable
    where fileid in (4028, 2090)
    group by first, last, amt, filldate
    having count(1) > 1) as duplicates
   on (duplicates.first = a.first
   and duplicates.last = a.last
   and duplicates.amt = a.amt
   and duplicates.filldate = a.filldate)
   ;
```

This will delete all duplicates even without defining which fileid to be deleted:

```
delete * from yourtable a
   inner join 
   (select  min(id) minid, first, last, amt, filldate             
    from yourtable
    group by first, last, amt, filldate
    having count(1) > 1) as duplicates
   on (duplicates.first = a.first
   and duplicates.last = a.last
   and duplicates.amt = a.amt
   and duplicates.filldate = a.filldate
   and duplicates.minid <> a.id)
   ;
```